# Nested resources with independent views model name error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

In routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :service_exps
end
```

user model:

```
has_many :service_exps
```

service_exps model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

In service_exps controller new action:

```
def new
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @service_exp = user.service_exps.build
  render :layout => false
end
```

In service_exps form:

```
= form_for ([@service_exp.user, @service_exp]), :remote => true do |s|
 .modal-body
  .row
    .span
      = s.label :org_name
      = s.text_field :org_name, :class => "span3"
  .row
    .span
      = s.label :position
      = s.text_field :position, :class => "span3"  
  .actions
    = s.submit 'Save',:class => "btn btn-info"
```

It give error

```
 undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

Please give any suggestion to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you are reaching service_exps controller new action?

Comment: hey santhosh, If click(ctrl+click) on @service_exp.user, it goes to new action.

Answer (score 0):

These type of errors are pretty easy to debug. The error msg says everything. You are calling a method (in this case 'user') on a nil object.

Follow these steps:

- Find the file and line no from the error msg.
- Find the object which is nil.
- Confirm that the object is initialized properly

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:`@service_exp = user.service_exps.build` will assign an array of objects to `@service_exp` - due to a user who `has_many :service_exps`.

In your view, you doing `@service_exp.user` - calling user on an array of objects which wont work. Something like `@service_exp.first.user` would though, when calling user on a specific object in the array. Or remove the .user from `form_for`

Comment: Carter shaw if I remove .user OR add @service_exp.first.user than it gives error 'undefined model_name'

Comment: Load a specific service_exp in your controller instead of an array of them

Comment: Can you not just call service_exp.new(pass params) in your new action?

Comment: yes but it not working because I calling service_exp form in user page so the association must be needed. I fix it but the solution little bit CRACKED. I use `=form_for (ServiceExp.new)` _form_for and create a new _edit_form for editing purpose and use here `= form_for (@service_exp)` and in controller normal action take place and in user model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :service_exps`